# proper location for public/private keys in my React development app?

Tags: reactjs

In the dev environment for my React app, I have a set of public/private keys that I need to access an API.  I'd like to ideally put these keys into their own file for gitignore purposes, but i'm not having luck with my code as shown below.

my `helpers.jsx` file is where the API data is called via lightweight AJAX add-on, and I have the actual keys in the `require` declarations area:

```
var API_KEY = require('./keys.jsx');
var PRIV_KEY = require('./keys.jsx');
```

Summarily, my `keys.jsx` file (stored in the same subfolder as the `helpers.jsx`) consists of the following:

```
module.exports = {
  API_KEY:'myactualpublickey',
  PRIV_KEY:'myactualprivatekey'
};
```

However, my app does not like this set up, as I get an `"Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 401 (Unauthorized)”` error message and the API call isn't successful because the necessary keys are not included.

When I replace the `require('./keys.jsx');` in the `helpers.jsx` file with the actual keys, the API call works fine.

Any help or guidance would be most appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're exporting an object with properties called `API_KEY` and `PRIV_KEY`, so try this:

```
var API_KEY  = require('./keys.jsx').API_KEY;
var PRIV_KEY = require('./keys.jsx').PRIV_KEY;
```